# use jsonp to get xml cross domain

Tags: xml, xss, cross-domain, jsonp

I am trying to read xml into a webpage from another server, and I assume that my problem is Same-Origin Policy, and therefore a cross domain problem.

I have a bit of googling and it seems that jsonp is the way forward.
Based on some examples I found here on stackoverflow and another sites, this is what I have, and it does not "hit" the server with the xml. I can view the xml in a  browser.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
   $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',                
        url: 'http://192.168.0.106:8111/getconfiguration?',
        success: function (xml) 
        { //do stuff with received xml 
        }});
```

Any suggestions? please keep in mind that I am a newbie with regards to JS / JQuery ;o)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have access to the server (if, for example, you're consuming an api) you can use
[YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) to convert your XML to jsonp and query the yahoo server from the browser using a custom custom YQL url (in which is embedded a SQL-like statement). Here's an example (for the zillow api):

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from zillow.search where address = "1835 73rd Ave NE" and citystatezip = "98039" and zwsid = "X1-ZWz1cse68iatcb_13bwv"&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env&callback=mydata',
    jsonpCallback: "mydata",
    success: function(results) {
      console.log(results.query.results.searchresults.response.results.result.zpid);
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to code generating the XML on the remote server, you can wrap the whole thing in jsonp.

JSONP is a way of getting around the same-origin policy by obtaining data via using `<script>` tags rather than trying to remotely extract information.

in your `getconfiguation` script, you would have something like

```
callback("SERVER GENERATED XML/JSON DATA GOES HERE");
```

where the callback is specified by the remote call

For instance, if your remote script was php, you would make it look something like this:

```
<?php
// getconfiguration.php
echo "$_GET['callback']($configuration_data);"
?>
```

Then make run AJAX you provided in your question.
What this actually does is dynamically insert a script tag into your page like this:

```
<script src="http://192.168.0.106:8111/getconfiguation.php?callback=???"></script>
```

jquery fills in the ??? for you with some unique wrapper it generated for your success callback

Comment: What if you don't have access to it? You can only send/receive data in xml format.

Comment: If the server is not set up to handle cross domain, clientside, javascript interactions, then you cannot force it to. There are various work arounds using a proxy on your server, flash or java applets.