# XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.reddit.com/.xml

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, cross-domain

Does anyone know how to fix this error? I am using jquery 1.6.2

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.reddit.com/.xml. Origin null is
>   not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.reddit.com/.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        crossDomain: true,
        success: xmlParser
    });

    // ...
});
```

Comment: Short answer is that `crossDomain` doesn't work out of the box with xml, but it _does_ work with JSONP.  Getting it to work with XML requires some additional work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need Help With Getting Cross Domain XML With JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550839/need-help-with-getting-cross-domain-xml-with-javascript)

Comment: Hi, I agree with Ray, see the following webpage for more detailed info: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/ Regards

Comment: I guess I can use the json version of the reddit api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [zrssfeed](http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed/) it'll make your life a lot easier, [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jedr6/1/).

```
$('#test').rssfeed('http://www.reddit.com/.xml');
```

Answer (score 0):

its because `same-origin-policy` create a server side proxy and have that proxy query the webservice and return your ajax request the xml response